# Como deixar checkbox do mat-select marcados como padrão

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Estou com um problema em uma projeto angular, tenho um `checkbox` dentro de um `<mat-select>` para fazer um filtro, entretanto eu desejo que todos os campos ja iniciem ativados e não desativados, segue código:

```js
export class ListarProdutoComponent implements OnInit {

table_dados: any = [];
table_config: any = [];
table_colunas: any = [];
allColumns = [];

rows = [];

temp = [];

columns = [
{ codigo: 'codigo' },
{ codigoProduto: 'codigoProduto' },
{ codigoSistema: 'codigoSistema' },
{ fornecedor: 'fornecedor' },
{ frete: 'frete' },
{ marca: 'marca' },
{ nome: 'nome' },
{ precoVenda: 'precoVenda' },
{ valor: 'valor' },
{ visivelVendas: 'visivelVendas' }
];




@ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;

constructor(private _tableService: TableService, private _produtoService: ProdutoService) {
this.table_config = tableData.configuracao;
this.table_colunas = tableData.configuracao.colunas;
this.allColumns  = this.table_colunas.slice(0);

toggle(col) {
    const isChecked = this.isChecked(col);

    if(isChecked) {
    this.table_colunas = this.table_colunas.filter(c => { 
        return c.name !== col.name; 
    });
    } else {
    this.table_colunas = [...this.table_colunas, col];
    }
}

isChecked(col) {
    return this.table_colunas.find(c => {
    return c.name === col.name;
    });
}


};
```

```html
           <mat-label>Checkbox</mat-label>       
            <mat-select  multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers" >
                <mat-option *ngFor="let col of allColumns"
                type='checkbox'
                [value]="col.name"
                (click)='toggle(col)'
                >{{col.name}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
           </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Você define `[value]=` duas vezes, pode não ter nada a ver, mas experimenta retirar um

Comment: Eu retirei aqui mas ainda não me deu o resultado, ele funciona normal o check, entretanto eu precisava que ele já viesse todos selecionados

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42149390/7206342

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-goeaud?file=app/select-multiple-example.html

Comment: Neste caso, adicionando `multiple` e  `[ngModel]="['Onion', 'Pepperoni']` ao select funcionou, mas conforme o outro link, dependendo da versão pode ser `value` ao invés de `ngModel`

Comment: Valeu bro, na verdade tudo que faltava era a falta do [formControl]="toppings"